# Ricci tensor proportional to Ricci scalar in 2D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

How can we prove that in 2D the Ricci scalar is proportional to the Ricci tensor? I started with the second Bianchi identity, set 2 axes equal - and it led me to the fact that in 2D the covariant derivative of the Ricci tensor is zero. However, I cannot prove that the Ricci tensor is proportional to the Ricci scalar from it.

Comment: References for 1+1 GR: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773866/226902, possible answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77990/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361333/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674975/226902

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to say that a tensor is proportional to a scalar.

Comment: How is this question any different from your previous [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783304/203278) about the Einstein tensor vanishing in 2D?